# Hex integer to decimal integer in Java

Tags: java, decimal, hex

I need to parse hex integer to decimal integer.

For example, Hex: *02 01* (*513* in decimal mode) should represent *201*.
In code it could pass:

```
Assert.assertEquals(201, parse(0x201));
```

How can I implement the method parse()? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Integer.toHexString()`

> System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(0x201));

Output : 201

Answer (score 2):

You can use the two-parameter version of [parseInt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
Assert.assertEquals(513, Integer.parseInt("201", 16));
```

Comment: I mean parse(0x201) should return 201.

Comment: @卢声远 Shengyuan Lu: You want to treat the hexadecimal number as if it were a decimal number? What do you do if the argument is `0x2f1`?

Comment: i think he's talking more on the representation side of things.   @卢声远 Shengyuan Lu: you should probably think of using a string representation in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to convert base 16 digits to base 10 digits, as follows:

```
int parse(int n) {
  if (n == 0) return 0;
  int digit = n & 0xf;
  assert digit >= 0 && digit <= 9;
  return parse(n >> 4) * 10 + digit;
}
```

probably won't work for negative numbers.

Why do you want to do this anyway?  Seems a pretty silly thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I find `String.format("%x", t)` works for the function. Anyway, thanks for Mark anirvan and Keith!